# How to organize different versioned REST API controllers in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I know there's a way to create versioned URLs for REST APIs with routes, but what's the best way to organize controllers and controller files? I want to be able to create new versions of APIs, and still keep the old ones running for at least some time.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I ended up using namespaces and directories under app/controllers:

```
/app
  /controllers
    /Api
      /v1
        /UserController.php
      /v2
        /UserController.php
```

And in UserController.php files I set the namespace accordingly:

```
namespace Api\v1;
```

or

```
namespace Api\v2;
```

Then in my routes I did something like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () {
  Route::get('user',      'Api\v1\UserController@index');
  Route::get('user/{id}', 'Api\v1\UserController@show');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v2'], function () {
  Route::get('user',      'Api\v2\UserController@index');
  Route::get('user/{id}', 'Api\v2\UserController@show');
});
```

I'm not positive this is the best solution. However, it has allowed versioning of the controllers in a way that they do not interfere with each other. You could probably do something verify similar with the models if needed.

Comment: When I used this method, I had to reference every class outside the name space using full path (example: \Input, \App)

Comment: You can also add a `use App;` statement. That's how namespaces work.

Comment: @iah.vector -  have problem with version, only must controller goes to v1 or model, job, request and... also must be go to vesrion folder?

Comment: @TravisMiller but how do you determine the version of the visitor?