# How to manage code duplication when versioning API?

Tags: api, rest, laravel-5, version

I'm studying Laravel REST, but maybe this does not limit itself to Laravel only.

Reading through articles and questions like [Laravel RESTful API versioning Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239823/laravel-restful-api-versioning-design) or [How to organize different versioned REST API controllers in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501010/how-to-organize-different-versioned-rest-api-controllers-in-laravel-4) (and a lot others) you get the concept that it's very important to version a API when building one.

But it seems to me that it may be a lot troublesome to manage different versions of your API using the separation of folders

```
 /app
  /controllers
    /Api
      /v1
        /UserController.php
      /v2
        /UserController.php
```

Looking from a near future, I can easily imagine having 30 files at v1 and 40 files at v2, for instance where about 20~25 files might be identical. Doesnt' this cause more troubles than solution?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: @JoseFrancis not quite. I haven't been developing API with multiple versions, but I'm now comfortable enough with Laravel to know that if the business requires 2 versions of the same controller, it's not bad to just have it. You can then refactor and try to move as much duplicate code as possible to a common Service/Gateway injected through Laravel IoC.

Answer (score 1):

If the changes are large enough, they will probably warrant a new Controller. But if not, you could pass the version number to the Controller instance, and route to the same controller. Then use that number to change behavior.